# asyncpg SELECT WHERE IN gives postgresSyntaxError

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, asyncpg

In my python code using asyncpg, I am passing in a tuple ('PENDING',) into a where-in query, which is logged as:

```
args=('TYPE_1', ('PENDING',))

query=SELECT * FROM actions where type = $1 AND status IN $2
```

It seems like the sql query should finally be

```
SELECT * FROM actions where type = TYPE_1 AND status in ('PENDING',);
```

but the above code results in:

```
asyncpg.exceptions.PostgresSyntaxError: syntax error at or near "$2"
```

I think it probably is because of the trailing comma in the tuple, but I don't know how to get rid of it..

Comment: It's definitely because of the trailing `,`. Why are you passing it with the `,`?

Comment: In python, I converted from array to tuple using tuple(status_list) which will yield the trailing comma

Answer (score 15):

In case this can help other people. In asyncpg, the WHERE IN is not supported any more. The correct way is to use `ANY`, therefore, when generating the sql codes, it should be:

```
WHERE type = $1 AND status = ANY($2::text[])
```

Where $2 is the regular python list. Looking at the `args`, it is now:

```
('TYPE_1', ['PENDING'])
```

Comment: How can I build a query where I've to do status not in ('PENDING')? 

I tried **status <> ANY($2::text[])** but it still fetches **PENDING** status

Comment: Okay got it. We can do something like **status <> ALL($2::text[])** i,e replacing **ANY** to **ALL** for negative cases :)

Comment: In other words `status NOT IN $2` would be `status != ALL($2::text[])`.